# Cannot read property 'tz' of undefined in moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="moment_timezone.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="moment_timezone_data_2010_2020.js"/> 
console.log(moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles").format());
```

Error is show  Cannot read property 'tz' of undefined in moment_timezone.js . i want to use moment js for converting time for diffrrent time zone .

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `moment.js` before `moment_timezone.js`

[Docs](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/browser/)

Comment: My error was: `Cannot read property 'version' of undefined` -- I had only included the timezone js file, not moment itself. This fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error you must import the library as follows:

```
'import timezone from 'moment-timezone'
```

Because moment-timezone uses below momentjs it is not necessary to import as such moment.